# Find duplicate field in another list using SPservices

Tags: sharepoint-server, spservices

When I'm adding a new item to a list Software, I want Country field would be compared to the Country field in another list (Countries) and if it's duplicate, I need to get an error and form couldn't be submitted.
Very similar to SPServices.SPRequireUnique function, only this function checks whether the field is duplicate in the same list. How to check the field in another list?

Software list:

| Title | Country |
| --- | --- |
| software1 | Poland |

Countries list from which I want to check field for duplicate:

| Country |
| --- |
| Lithuania |
| USA |

SPServices.SPRequireUnique function:

```
$().SPServices.SPRequireUnique({
columnStaticName: "Country",
duplicateAction: 1,
ignoreCase: true,
initMsg: "",
initMsgCSSClass: "ms-vb",
errMsg: "Duplicate country",
errMsgCSSClass: "ms-formvalidation",
showDupes: true,
completefunc: null
});
```

I want to achieve this when I create new item and enter duplicate country name which is in another list:
[image: new item with duplicate country]

**P.S. I can't use PowerApps or InfoPath, best option would be to achieve this with jQuery**

Comment: Use `PreSaveAction()` function instead, inside the function use REST call on 2nd list to check if items are available for same county. If items found, show an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by editing SPservices.js:

```
$.fn.SPServices.SPRequireUniqueCountry = function (options) {

    var opt = $.extend({}, {
        columnStaticName: "Country", // Name of the column
        duplicateAction: 1, // 0 = warn, 1 = prevent
        ignoreCase: true, // If set to true, the function ignores case, if false it looks for an exact match
        initMsg: "", // Initial message to display after setup
        initMsgCSSClass: "ms-vb", // CSS class for initial message
        errMsg: "Duplicate country", // Error message to display if not unique
        errMsgCSSClass: "ms-formvalidation", // CSS class for error message
        showDupes: true, // If true, show links to the duplicate item(s) after the error message
        completefunc: null // Function to call on completion of rendering the change.
    }, options);

    // Get the current item's ID from the Query String
    var queryStringVals = $().SPServices.SPGetQueryString();
    var thisID = queryStringVals.ID;
    currentContext.thisList = $().SPServices.SPListNameFromUrl();

    // Set the messages based on the options provided
    var msg = "<span id='SPRequireUnique" + opt.columnStaticName + "' class='{0}'>{1}</span><br/>";
    var firstMsg = msg.replace(/\{0\}/g, opt.initMsgCSSClass).replace(/\{1\}/g, opt.initMsg);

    // We need the DisplayName
    var columnDisplayName = $().SPServices.SPGetDisplayFromStatic({
        listName: currentContext.thisList,
        columnStaticName: opt.columnStaticName
    });
    var columnObj = findFormField(columnDisplayName).find("input[Title^='" + columnDisplayName + "']");
    columnObj.parent().append(firstMsg);

    columnObj.blur(function () {
        var columnValueIDs = [];
        // Get the columnDisplayName's value
        var columnValue = $(this).val();
        if (columnValue.length === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        // Call the Lists Web Service (GetListItems) to see if the value already exists
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            listName: "Countries",
            // Make sure we get all the items, ignoring any filters on the default view.
            CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Title'/></IsNotNull></Where></Query>",
            // Filter based on columnStaticName's value
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
            // Override the default view rowlimit and get all appropriate rows
            CAMLRowLimit: 0,
            completefunc: function (xData) {
                var testValue = opt.ignoreCase ? columnValue.toUpperCase() : columnValue;
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                    var thisValue = opt.ignoreCase ? $(this).attr("ows_" + opt.columnStaticName).toUpperCase() : $(this).attr("ows_" + opt.columnStaticName);
                    // If this value already exists in columnStaticName and it's not the current item, then save the ID in the array
                    if ((testValue === thisValue) && ($(this).attr("ows_ID") !== thisID)) {
                        columnValueIDs.push([$(this).attr("ows_ID"), $(this).attr("ows_" + opt.columnStaticName)]);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        var newMsg = opt.initMsg;
        var msgContainer = $("#SPRequireUnique" + opt.columnStaticName);
        msgContainer.html(newMsg).attr("class", opt.initMsgCSSClass);

        $("input[value='OK']:disabled, input[value='Save']:disabled").removeAttr("disabled");
        if (columnValueIDs.length > 0) {
            newMsg = opt.errMsg;
            msgContainer.html(newMsg).attr("class", opt.errMsgCSSClass);
            if (opt.duplicateAction === 1) {
                columnObj.focus();
                $("input[value='OK'], input[value='Save']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
            if (opt.showDupes) {
                var out = " "+ ": ";
                for (i = 0; i < columnValueIDs.length; i++) {
                    out += "<a href='../countries/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + columnValueIDs[i][0] + "&Source=" + location.href + "'>" + columnValueIDs[i][1] + "</a> ";
                }
                $("span#SPRequireUnique" + opt.columnStaticName).append(out);
            }
        }

    });
    // If present, call completefunc when all else is done
    if (opt.completefunc !== null) {
        opt.completefunc();
    }
}; // End $.fn.SPServices.SPRequireUniqueCountry
```